# Список переписки с пользователями

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть вот такой вот блок, где выводится users с кем я ввел переписку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу выводить фотку, имя и последнее сообщение. Почти все хорошо, но в моем случае дублируются пользователи, как видно на примере Катя фигурирует 2 раза. Так быть не должно.

Вот так выглядит мой запрос:

```
 $query = 'SELECT

                m.message AS message,
                fu.username AS username,
                fu.img AS img,
                fu.id as id,
                m.message_status as status,
                m.id as idm,
                m.id_for
              FROM
                users AS fu
              LEFT JOIN
                user_message AS m
              ON
                m.id_for = fu.user_id
              WHERE
                m.id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"
                order by idm desc
                ';

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $ar = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
        $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $ar[] = $arr;
```

Пробовал после запроса, перед тем как закидывать данные в массив, сравнивать id(мол если такой есть, то закидывать в массив не нужно) но по неизвестной мне причине не получилось))

Comment: Заведите просто таблицу `last_messages`, которую обновляйте по приходу каждого сообщения. И из нее делайте простую выборку. И работает быстро, и с запросами корпеть не надо.

Comment: возможно, я скажу глупость, но я не понимаю, как при left join можно получить дубли. я бы в первую очередь таблицу юзеров посмотрел

Comment: Дублирует, по таблице user_message, она состоит из id, user_from, user_to, status и date

Comment: WHERE ... GROUP BY id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот такой запрос

```
SELECT m.message AS message,
       fu.username AS username,
       fu.img AS img,
       fu.id as id,
       m.message_status as status,
       m.id as idm,
       m.id_for
  FROM users AS fu
  LEFT JOIN user_message AS m ON m.id_for = fu.user_id
 WHERE m.id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"
   AND m.id = (SELECT MAX(m2.id) 
                 FROM message m2 
                WHERE m2.id_for = fu.user_id AND m2.id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'")
```

Используется внутренний запрос для нахождения максимального id. В результат попадёт только одно сообщение для пары m.id_for, m.id_from.
Работает с древних времён, когда SQL ещё не оброс новыми возможностями

Такой вариант. Не знаю правильно ли в данном случае ссылаться из подзапроса на поля из внешнего запроса (`id_for = fu.user_id`).

```
SELECT m.message AS message,
       fu.username AS username,
       fu.img AS img,
       fu.id as id,
       m.message_status as status,
       m.id as idm,
       m.id_for
  FROM users AS fu
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, message, id_for, id_from
               FROM user_message
              WHERE id_for = fu.user_id AND id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"
              ORDER BY id DESC
              LIMIT 1) AS m
```

Используется join с подзапросом, который вытаскивает только последнее сообщение (`ORDER BY id DESC` и `LIMIT 1`)
Первый вариант тоже можно переделать на `LIMIT` вместо `MAX`

Ещё можно вставить подзапрос в список полей главного запроса.
    `SELECT ... (SELECT ... FROM ...) ... FROM ...`
Таким нехитрым образом наверно можно как-то вставить мессагу. Но я такого никогда не делал и выдумывать лом.

А если бы использовали `Postgres`, то можно было бы сделать так

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.id_for, m.id_from)
       m.message AS message,
       fu.username AS username,
       fu.img AS img,
       fu.id as id,
       m.message_status as status,
       m.id as idm,
       m.id_for
  FROM users AS fu
  LEFT JOIN user_message AS m ON m.id_for = fu.user_id
 WHERE m.id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"
 ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

От Вашего запроса отличается только добавлением `DISTINCT ON (m.id_for, m.id_from)`, что заставит `postgres` подобрать только первую запись для пары (m.id_for, m.id_from), а остальные проигнорировать.